# strlen() dosn't count with if/else statments

Tags: php, html

I want to count my text from database and if it is more than (ex. 100) characters i want to display a button Read More so when you clck it it sends me to full text here are my codes:

**index.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div id='posts'>
        <h3>".$row['titulli']."</h3>
        <h5>".$row['data']."</h5>
        <p>".$row['teksti']."</p>
        ".$count = $row['teksti']; 
         echo "<button><a href='post.php?titulli=".$row['titulli']."&data=".$row['data']."'>Read More</a></button></div>";
        }
```

I added an if statment but i think i have an error writing it:
When i add this code to it, it totaly brakes my page

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div id='posts'>
        <h3>".$row['titulli']."</h3>
        <h5>".$row['data']."</h5>
        <p>".$row['teksti']."</p>
        ".$count = $row['teksti'];
        if (strlen($count > 100)) {
            echo "<button><a href='post.php?titulli=".$row['titulli']."&data=".$row['data']."'>Read More</a></button></div>";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You're now also closing the `</div>` conditionally inside the `if`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your function call of [strlen()](http://php.net/strlen)

```
if(strlen($count > 100))
```

Should be:

```
if(strlen($count) > 100)
```

Take note of the location of the parentheses.

Comment: Thank u the problem was very simple but it helped me so much. But if i want to not show more than 100 characters ?

Comment: You can either add an `} else {` statement to catch when the first criteria is not met or add an `} elseif (...) {` to explicitly provide criteria for less than.  The first route would catch it by assuming that if its not greater than 100 then it is less than.